# R: for loop iteration with seq_along vectors of a list

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

consider the following code:

```
listLength <- sample(1:10, 1)
vectorLength <- sample(1:10, 1)

x <- vector("list")

for(i in 1:listLength){

  x[[i]] <- sample(1:10, vectorLength)
}


transform <- function(x){

  result <- vector("list")

  for(i in seq_along(x[[1]])){ 

    temp <- vector("numeric")

    for(j in seq_along(x)){

      temp <- c(temp, x[[j]][i])

    }

    result[[i]] <- temp

  }

  return(result)


}
```

and finally

```
y <- transform(x)
```

x is a list of random length , the vector elements of x have a random, but always equal length.

The transform function returns a new list y, which is a list of vectorLength with vectors of listLength.

**The question:**

```
for(i in seq_along(x[[1]]))
```

Is this the common way to go? Just take the length of the first element in the for loop? Or is there some kind of sublength function which gives the length of every sub element.

Of course I could just use the vectorLength variable, but think of it as a complex algorithm which just produces the x variable.

I feel like this is bad coding...

Comment: x eventually becomes a 10x10 array, why not declare it like that at the start? Doing memory allocation once instead of multiple appends, reallocs and memmoves is faster. What calculation do you then do using x, by the way? Array stuff? something else?

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I rushed the question and didn't express myself good enough, I added the code in the function so it becomes more clearly

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want the result to look like. Could you add an example?

Comment: Edited it, had to add text before y <- transform(x) because otherwise it wouldn't show up, i dont know why..

Comment: Why are you obsessed with appending to list-of-list, just declare an Nx10 array, initialized to NA, and fill in the elements. You haven't given us any reason why that wouldn't be better.

Comment: Because there is an algorithm which produces the list in my case, I can't change that. This is just an reproducible example and I don't see how that should answer my question concerning the for loop? I have to admit I'm relatively new to R, so maybe you could show a working code example as Answer.

Comment: x is a list which is returned from an algorithm. The reason I chose y as a list in the first place was because I wanted the vectors to be kind of seperated from each other because they do not relate to each other. What would be the advantage of an array? You said it is faster, but I can't see how I could benefit from that since I'm not dealing with huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `mapply` to run that "fancy stuff" in a function. The one surprise might be that it returns its matrix results in column-major order rather than what you might have expected (which is easy enought to fix by wrapping that with `t(.)`

```
mapply(function(x,y) c(x,y,seq(y,y+(y-x),length=8)), x,x2)
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
 [1,]  1.00000  2.00000  3.00000  4.00000  5.00000  6.00000
 [2,] 11.00000 12.00000 13.00000 14.00000 15.00000 16.00000
 [3,] 11.00000 12.00000 13.00000 14.00000 15.00000 16.00000
 [4,] 12.42857 13.42857 14.42857 15.42857 16.42857 17.42857
 [5,] 13.85714 14.85714 15.85714 16.85714 17.85714 18.85714
 [6,] 15.28571 16.28571 17.28571 18.28571 19.28571 20.28571
 [7,] 16.71429 17.71429 18.71429 19.71429 20.71429 21.71429
 [8,] 18.14286 19.14286 20.14286 21.14286 22.14286 23.14286
 [9,] 19.57143 20.57143 21.57143 22.57143 23.57143 24.57143
[10,] 21.00000 22.00000 23.00000 24.00000 25.00000 26.00000
          [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
 [1,]  7.00000  8.00000  9.00000 10.00000
 [2,] 17.00000 18.00000 19.00000 20.00000
 [3,] 17.00000 18.00000 19.00000 20.00000
 [4,] 18.42857 19.42857 20.42857 21.42857
 [5,] 19.85714 20.85714 21.85714 22.85714
 [6,] 21.28571 22.28571 23.28571 24.28571
 [7,] 22.71429 23.71429 24.71429 25.71429
 [8,] 24.14286 25.14286 26.14286 27.14286
 [9,] 25.57143 26.57143 27.57143 28.57143
[10,] 27.00000 28.00000 29.00000 30.00000
```

The transposed output:

```
> t(mapply(function(x,y) c(x,y,seq(y,y+(y-x),length=8)), x,x2))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
 [1,]    1   11   11 12.42857 13.85714 15.28571 16.71429 18.14286
 [2,]    2   12   12 13.42857 14.85714 16.28571 17.71429 19.14286
 [3,]    3   13   13 14.42857 15.85714 17.28571 18.71429 20.14286
 [4,]    4   14   14 15.42857 16.85714 18.28571 19.71429 21.14286
 [5,]    5   15   15 16.42857 17.85714 19.28571 20.71429 22.14286
 [6,]    6   16   16 17.42857 18.85714 20.28571 21.71429 23.14286
 [7,]    7   17   17 18.42857 19.85714 21.28571 22.71429 24.14286
 [8,]    8   18   18 19.42857 20.85714 22.28571 23.71429 25.14286
 [9,]    9   19   19 20.42857 21.85714 23.28571 24.71429 26.14286
[10,]   10   20   20 21.42857 22.85714 24.28571 25.71429 27.14286
          [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 19.57143    21
 [2,] 20.57143    22
 [3,] 21.57143    23
 [4,] 22.57143    24
 [5,] 23.57143    25
 [6,] 24.57143    26
 [7,] 25.57143    27
 [8,] 26.57143    28
 [9,] 27.57143    29
[10,] 28.57143    30
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I rushed the question and didn't express myself good enough, I added the code in the function so it becomes more clearly.